# How to add authenticated publication url in qualtrics?

Tags: qualtrics

I am going through below post to add create event subscription.
  https://api.qualtrics.com/docs/listen-to-and-retrieve-responses-in-real-time

In my case, publicationURL is protected by basic authentication, How can I subscribe to this protected url (I mean how can I convey credentials here)?

Any idea about the complete survey payload format, any documentation link helps....

Thanks,
Hari